# How significant is the time lag between inertial IMU data in a inertial analisys?

Tags: sensor

I'm working on a MCU system that use an IMU (ICM-20948) which has two different chip inside: one provides accelerometer and gyroscope data at $1125$ Hz (configurable at $125$ Hz), the other one magnetometer data at fixed $100$ Hz (not configurable).

Now I'm wondering how much the non-synchronicity of the data could be a problem in a motion processing algorithms.

Comment: The fact that they run at two different rates (especially since they are rationally related) doesn't imply they are non-synchronous – you just might need to resample one or both streams of data to a common rate if you were to directly combine them, or a derived observation down the processing line.

Comment: @MarcusMüller what do you mean with "rationally related"? So you are saying that if I take the inertial values from the registers of the sensors at MY frequency of 300 Hz for example (keeping the accelerometer and gyroscope data at 1125 Hz and magnetometer data at 100 Hz) it's not a problem in a motion process algorithm (AHRS)? Because in that case I'll have three identical samples for the magnetometer for every acc/gyr sample.

Comment: If you have a fast and a slow sensor, you can always interpolate/decimate either or both to simulate that they were running at the same rate. The fact that there's common factors in both rates ("rationally related") just makes that easier.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your algorithm, and on whether the timing is known.

Assuming that the timing of each measurement is known, you can incorporate measurements at unsynchronized moments by executing a Kalman update step for the measurements you have, at the moment the measurements happened -- just use a measurement matrix ($H$ in most Kalman literature) that matches the measurement you have, and do your update.

This does mean that you need to use the appropriate state update equations, which makes for the filter design being a royal pain in the behind -- but it's more a matter of dotting a bunch of 'i's and crossing a bunch of 't's (and not crossing 'i's or dotting 't's) than it is a matter of the basic math getting worse.

Comment: And if I don't know the time between the actual sampling of each inertial sensor? In my example I can get the accelerometer and gyroscope almost instantanely through the use of interrupt but for the magnetometer I could have an timing error of 5ms respect to the other sensors in the worst case (if the interrupt trigger in the middle of two magnetometer's samples).

Comment: If the timing is that important, then you should arrange to know it, by changing your hardware design if necessary.  If, for instance, you have chips or a chip with "measurement completed" status pins, you could use hardware timers to capture the time at which those pins went active, and use that time -- rather than the time that the interrupt executed -- as your nominal time of measurement.